# Restrict access to nodejs express routes

Tags: node.js, express, http

I have "internal" routes in my app :

```
app.get('/myroute', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('Hello!');
});
```

But the  route is also accessible from outside:

```
curl http://example.com/myroute/?this=that
```

How to restrict the use of this route to the app / domain itself, ideally with a nice error?

Comment: You can't really restrict access.  If the route is in your web server, then anyone with curl or any scripting tool can hit the route.  You can implement access control to require credentials and return an error if the appropriate credentials are not provided.  If this route is really internal to just your server, then don't make it a route at all, just make it into a function that you call.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "restrict use of the route to the app/domain itself".  Please clarify exactly what you mean by that.  Provide examples of what you want to allow access to and what you want to deny access to.  Keep in mind that access from a web page is not access from your domain.  That's access from a web page that came from your domain, but the access is actually coming from some user's browser.  I have no idea what access from your app means?

Comment: What does internal mean? Do you mean it's only meant to be called by clients you control? Sounds like you want authentication.

Comment: The only way I know to get data back and forth between an express server and the client browser is using a route, maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, you have a few options:

1. Consider whether this route needs to be a web route at all, and not a function.  If it's internal, surely a function would suffice?
2. Create a 'shared secret' for this function that must appear in either the header or as a request param.  Then only callers that know this secret can call it.